# jQuery.each for lists and non-lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a `jQuery.each(data, foo)`, where data is either a string or a list of strings. I'd like to know if there's an existing utility function to convert the string to a list, or otherwise perform `foo` on just the string. So instead of the easy route:

```
if (!$.isArray(data)) {
  foo(0, data); // can't rely on `this` variable
} else {
  $.each(data,foo);
}
```

I was just wondering if there was already a builtin function of jQuery or Javascript that would convert data to a list automatically, like this:

```
function convert_to_list(data) { return $.isArray(data) ? data : [data]; }

$.each(convert_to_list(data), foo);
```

Just curious!

Thanks for reading.

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andy's approach is a good one. Alternatively, you can always force data to be an array and then feed to jQuery.each

```
if(typeof data == 'string') {
    data = [data];
}
jQuery.each(data, foo);
```

Another option is to always wrap the input in an array regardless of it's type (string or array), and then flatten it. `flatten`, as the name suggests, will flatten multi-level arrays to a single level. So `[["foo", "bar"]]` becomes `["foo", "bar"]`. The code them becomes:

```
jQuery.each([data].flatten(), foo);
```

Various libraries provide the flatten method, and a pure JavaScript implementation can be found [here](http://tech.karbassi.com/2009/12/17/pure-javascript-flatten-array/) and another [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Reduce#Example.3a_Flatten_an_array_of_arrays) at MDC that only flattens arrays two levels deep.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than converting to an array, you could "bind" the string to `foo` using [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply) or [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Call):

```
if (!$.isArray(data)) {
  foo.call(data, 0); // `this` will point to data
} else {
  $.each(data,foo);
}
```